# Ansible - keys missing after changing values in a dict

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I want to change all the values "b" in a way that I will divide it with some number.
Here is the code:

```yaml
    - name: code
      hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: false
    
      vars:
        dict1: [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 5, "b": 5, "c": 6},{"a": 8, "b": 9, "c": 10}]
        dict2: |
          [
          {% for i in dict1 %}
          {{ i.a, (i.b/2)|int, i.c }},
          {% endfor %}
          ]
    
      tasks: 

      - debug:
          var: dict2|type_debug
      - debug:
          var: dict2
```

Problem with this is that I've got just values and "keys" are missing

> ok: [localhost] => {
> "dict2": [
> [
> 1,
> 1,
> 3
> ],
> [
> 5,
> 2,
> 6
> ],
> [
> 8,
> 4,
> 10
> ]
> ]

What should I change to include keys too?

Also, not that important, but I've got [ ] instead { } for each item in the loop (simple replacement [] with {} in the variable dict2 doesn't work).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `dict1` is a list of dicts. This means that you cannot simply define a list of values, but must also create a dict again.

There are surely different approaches for this, one is the following:

```yaml
dict1: [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 5, "b": 5, "c": 6},{"a": 8, "b": 9, "c": 10}]
dict2: |
  [
  {% for i in dict1 %}
  {{ dict( ['a', 'b', 'c'] | zip( [i.a, (i.b/2)|int, i.c] ) ) }},
  {% endfor %}
  ]
```

1. a list with the values `a`, `b` and `c` is defined
2. another list with the values for *a*, *b*, *c* is created
3. both lists are connected by [`zip()`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-items-from-multiple-lists-zip-and-zip-longest).
4. the resulting zip lists are converted to a dict by `dict()`.

The result of `- debug: var=dict2` looks like this:

```
TASK [debug] **********************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "dict2": [
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 1,
            "c": 3
        },
        {
            "a": 5,
            "b": 2,
            "c": 6
        },
        {
            "a": 8,
            "b": 4,
            "c": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: They said avoid comments like thanks, but still I would like to thank you :)